# Excel Adding multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I sum the "1"s separate from the "2"s when they are in the same column?

```
1
2
   1
   1
   1
   1
   2
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
1
   1
   1
   1
   2
   1
   2
   1
   2
   2
   1
   1
   1
   1
   2
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   2
   1
   2
   2
```

Answer (score 4):

SUM values 1:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100;1;A1:A100)
```

SUM values 2:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100;2;A1:A100)
```